# Pass save parameter through Django create method

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have the following Django model, which overrides the save method:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, lock=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if lock:
            print("LOCKING OBJECT...")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know I can create a person and pass `lock` to the save method like so:

```
steve = Person(name="Steve")
steve.save(lock=True)
# LOCKING OBJECT...
```

However, I really enjoy using the `create` method, as it's much more readable:

```
Person.objects.create(name="Michelle")
```

How can I pass `lock` using the latter approach? The following doesn't work:

```
Person.objects.create(name="Michelle", lock=True)
# TypeError: Person() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lock'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add additional methods to the Person manager (the `objects` object) by creating a custom manager for your model:

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def create_person(*args, **kwargs):
        lock = kwargs.pop('lock', False)
        new_person = self.model(**kwargs)
        new_person.save(lock=lock)
        return new_person
```

then add that new manager to your model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = PersonManager() #Here!

    def save(self, lock=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if lock:
            print("LOCKING OBJECT...")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can call

```
Person.objects.create_person(name='Pablo', lock=True)
```

You can also override the function name `create` but that could have unintended effects, so I wouldn't.

Note that this is a common pattern in Django apps, like Auth

Comment: I agree with this answer because the other solution would require overriding the create method - which could introduce more issues than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with `create`, you can always do by overriding constructor of your model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._lock = kwargs.pop('lock', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lock = kwargs.pop('lock', self._lock)
        if lock:
            print("LOCKING OBJECT...")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now this will work with

```
Person.objects.create_person(name='Pablo', lock=True)
```

and

```
steve = Person(name="Steve")
steve.save(lock=True)
```

Please note that django's official documentation does not recommend [overriding model's constructor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects). But if you want to do, you can do.